# Set scene size to view size?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm using SpriteKit, and I want the size of the scene to be equal to the size of the view.

In code, this is easy to do:

I simple add in the following in "viewDidLoad":

`scene.size = skView.bounds.size`

However, I am working with the sks editor too. Is there a way for me to set the scene size to the view size in the sks file? Currently, the sks file says my dimensions are 1024 and 768.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the size you want like this:

```
GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 768)];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
```

Comment: How is this different from the piece of code I posted?

Comment: @asdf - This lets you programmatically change the view size to whatever you want.

Comment: I was looking for a way to change it in the sks file though.